# Access plugin helper methods and lib on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-plugins, communityengine

I am currently delevoping a community using Community Engine, but I need to add some models.

The problem is that I need the helpers methods that are used by CE, but when I try to access the new sections of the site, I get a undefined method (like below)

```
undefined method `logged_in?' for #<ActionView::Base:0x1048f3748>
```

The logged_in? method is at vendor/plugins/community_engine/lib/authenticated_system.rb

These method is defined as a helper method like this:

```
# this is at vendor/plugins/community_engine/lib/authenticated_system.rb
def self.included(base)
  base.send :helper_method, :current_user, :current_user_session, :logged_in?, :admin?, :moderator?
end
```

How can I make my rails application load all the helpers and the methods declared in lib of my plugins?

Comment: did you `include AuthenticatedSystem` in your `ApplicationController`?

Comment: I can add the AuthenticadedSystem because that's a module but I can't include/require the helpers =S Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can edit your file vendor/plugins/community_engine/init.rb and add this line to load it:

```
ActionView::Base.send(:include, MyHelper)
```

and move you helper in your folder vendor/plugins/community_engine/helpers

```
module MyHelper
  def my_method_here
    ...
  end
end
```

Hope this help!

Answer (score 0):

Most sites that I've worked with physically copy the `authenticated_system.rb` file into `#{RAILS_ROOT}/lib` and check it in.

That way you can override the methods if you need to.

Comment: And what about the helpers? I can include the module, but still having trouble with the helpers =S

Comment: The library I mention above is the one that includes all of the helper methods in it. If you copy it into the lib directory, then use `include AuthenticatedSystem` in your controller - it will find the helper methods.

Comment: I've copied the module in the RAILS_ROOT/lib directory but the helpers (vendor/plugins/community_engine/app/helpers/) are still giving me problems =S I can't use those methods in my custom models =S

Comment: wait - why do you need them in your *model*? a helper like "logged-in" is a controller/view-level access control method.